# Return string and increment integer in same method

Tags: java

I want to return a string and increment an integer in the same method.

```
Public String method()
{
    Return string;
    i++;
}
```

This is what my limited mind could think of, but it is obviously not going to work.

Is this possible, if it is how?

Comment: why not just swap the lines?

Comment: Your question is pretty vague, but just reverse the order.  Increment first, and then return your string.

Comment: Also, since this is java, spell "return" and "public" correctly.  Both begin with lower case.

Comment: After you return a value from function the next won't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few points...
 Return should be the last statement in your method as it exits the method.
 Case is important in JAva so return needs to be all lowercase, like every keyword in Java.
 Might as well keep an integer that you can increment every time it's called.

```
public class TestClass
{
  int i = 0;  //integer to increment

  public String exampleMethod()
  {
    int++;
    return "Test String"; //string to return
  }
}
```

Returning the string and the integer would be the next step.

Comment: Not at all.  Added some more description, please accept an answer if it answered your question.

Comment: I will in 4 min when i'm allowed

Answer (score 1):

well, first of all, the return statement is always the last line and not uppercase.
Same with public....no uppercase.

To increment i, you need to make it a member variable. 
Ex:

```
public class YourClassName{

//members here
int i;

    public YourClassName(){
       i = 0
    }

    public String method(){
        i++;
        return string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless the method can branch (if conditions, switch statements etc.) or terminate prematurely (e.g. in the case of an exception), the return statement will always be the last line to execute before control is *return*ed to its caller. Hence you should finish any work before returning.

In other words, swap your two lines of code:

```
public String method()
{
    i++;
    return string;
}
```